# Not able to create shortcut with name as com.example.myapp.exe

Tags: c#

I have a utility that creates a shortcut to desktop.
My application for which I am creating a shortcut name as "com.example.myapp.exe"

this app shared in intranet network and all the system will have a network drive(possibly H:) so full path of my app will be like "H:/network apps/com.example.myapp.exe"

Now my utility is taking this path and creating shortcut to desktop, but the problem is that the created link is not valid it's point to path "H:/network apps/com.exe"

Code:

```
string destPath =  Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.CommonDesktopDirectory);
string shortcutName = @"com.example.myapp.exe - shortcut.lnk";
string path = System.IO.Path.Combine(destPath, shortcutName);

WshShellClass wsh = new WshShellClass();
IWshRuntimeLibrary.IWshShortcut shortcut = wsh.CreateShortcut(path) as IWshRuntimeLibrary.IWshShortcut;
shortcut.TargetPath = @"H:/network apps/com.example.myapp.exe";
shortcut.WorkingDirectory = @"H:/network apps/";
shortcut.Save();

//created shortcut path is H:/network apps/com.exe
```

How to correct this path..

**Note: if I use normal drive(C:) folder shortcut path is right "C:/network apps/com.example.myapp.exe"**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I played around with your code and determine if the Drive Letter doesn't exist, it doesn't work.

Since I have N: mapped, I changed your code to the following:

```
shortcut.TargetPath = @"N:\network apps\com.example.myapp.exe";
shortcut.WorkingDirectory = @"N:\network apps\";
```

And it created the shortcut with the proper path.

To test my theory, I modified your code to create a link for each drive letter:

```
using System;
using IWshRuntimeLibrary;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {

            for (char letter = Char.Parse("A"); letter <= Char.Parse("Z"); letter++)
            {
                string destPath = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.CommonDesktopDirectory);
                string shortcutName = string.Format("{0} - com.example.myapp.exe - shortcut.lnk", letter);
                string path = System.IO.Path.Combine(destPath, shortcutName);

                IWshShell_Class wsh = new IWshShell_Class();
                IWshRuntimeLibrary.IWshShortcut shortcut = wsh.CreateShortcut(path) as IWshRuntimeLibrary.IWshShortcut;
                shortcut.TargetPath = string.Format(@"{0}:\network apps\com.example.myapp.exe", letter);
                shortcut.WorkingDirectory = string.Format(@"{0}:\network apps\", letter);
                shortcut.Save();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Even after mapping I got the same issue. but able to resolve it by adding condition to check **System.IO.File.Exists(@"H:\network apps\com.example.myapp.exe")**

Comment: Then got to know my program is not able to access mapped network drive path some permission issue in my computer. When I run the same utility in test system, it worked fine.